# Graph of a parametric curve that depends on an integral

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, parametric-functions

I want to plot the following function:

[image: tractrix]

I have tried to define the function with this code:

```
r[t_] := {Exp[-t], NIntegrate[Sqrt[1 - Exp[-2 u]], {u, 0, t}],t >= 0}
r[t_] := {Exp[-t], NIntegrate[Sqrt[1 - Exp[2 u]], {u, 0, t}],t<=0}
```

But it does not work. I am new to this, I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
r1[t_] := {Exp[-t], NIntegrate[Sqrt[1 - Exp[-2 u]], {u, 0, t}]}

r2[t_] := {Exp[t], NIntegrate[Sqrt[1 - Exp[2 u]], {u, 0, t}]}

r[t_] := Piecewise[{{r1[t], t >= 0}, {r2[t], t <= 0}}]

Plot[r[t], {t, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Red}]
```

[image]

or this?

```
ParametricPlot[r[t], {t, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Red}]
```

Comment: Exactly, with `ParametricPlot`, now I can visualize the curve. I really appreciate your help.